# why my code is printing output for input text containing more than 10 characters?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
  char ch, a[10];
  int i = 0;
  printf("enter text,press <return> to end!\n");
  while (ch != '\n') {
    ch = getchar();
    a[i] = ch;
    i++;
  }
  i = i - 1;
  a[i] = '\0';
  printf("%s", a);
}
```

here i declared an array 'a' of maximum size 10.I used a while loop to read characters and place them in array 'a' and finally the code prints the text i have entered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a little more checking in this version.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRLEN 10    

int main(void) {                                               // correct signature
    char ch, a[STRLEN+1];                                      // room for terminator
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter text, press <return> to end!\n");
    while(i < STRLEN && (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') // more checks
        a[i++]=ch;                                             // excludes newline
    a[i]='\0';                                                 // terminate string
    printf("%s\n",a);                                          // added newline
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really unsafe as you have a statically declared array of 10 `char`s. If the user enters a 11th `char` you will encounter buffer overflow. You should check `i` in your `while` too:

```
while(ch!='\n' && i < 9) {
ch=getchar();
a[i]=ch;
i++;
}
a[i]='\0';
printf("%s",a);
```

Comment: But the array can't hold more than 10 elements right? even though 'i' is incrementing the array should terminate when it encounters 11th element.The array size should keep track of the entered characters.But why not it's working in that way?